# Typescript express - gulp exclude compile error

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, gulp, definitelytyped

I have little problem with compiling typescript with gulp. I've set exclude directory in my tsconfig, but I'm getting *.d.ts errors:

```
    typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1965,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Transform'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1987,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PassThrough'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1992,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'showHidden'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1993,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'depth'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1994,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'colors'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(1995,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'customInspect'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2056,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2064,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isRaw'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2066,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isTTY'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2069,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'columns'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2070,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'rows'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2071,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isTTY'.
typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2078,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
typings/browser/ambient/serve-static/index.d.ts(85,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/body-parser/index.d.ts(138,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(22,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'path'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(23,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'stack'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(81,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'all'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(82,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'get'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(83,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'post'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(84,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'put'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(85,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'delete'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(86,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'patch'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(87,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'options'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(88,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'head'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(107,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ma
ge'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(108,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'signed'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(109,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'expires'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(110,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'httpOnly'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(111,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'path'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(112,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'domain'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(113,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'secure'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(145,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'headers'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(242,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'accepted'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(293,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'protocol'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(300,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'secure'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(307,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ip'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(317,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ips'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(330,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'subdomains'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(335,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'path'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(340,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'hostname'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(345,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'host'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(352,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'fresh'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(359,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'stale'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(364,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'xhr'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(367,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'body'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(370,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'cookies'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(372,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'method'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(374,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'params'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(376,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'user'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(378,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'authenticatedUser'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(388,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'query'.
/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/expressTypescript/typings/main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts(390,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'route'.
```

This is only part of errors, but everything are from same folder.
**My gulpfile**:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { typescript: require('typescript') });

gulp.task('Build_typescript', function () {
return tsProject.src([paths.typescriptDir + "*.ts", "!" + paths.documentRoot + "baseDir.ts", "!" + paths.documentRoot + "_all.d.ts"])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

**and tsconfig with es5 from Angular2**:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
//"typings/browser",
//"typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**All my *.d.ts references I have in one file _all.d.ts**:

```
    /// <reference path="../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />
```

**browser:**

```
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/body-parser/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/express/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/mime/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/serve-static/index.d.ts" />
```

**main:**

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/body-parser/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/express/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/mime/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/serve-static/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts" />
```

**In my project, I call refefences on top of file:**

```
/// <reference path="../_all.d.ts" />

import mongoose = require("mongoose");

export var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string;
}

export var repository = mongoose.model<IUser>("Userma");
```

I realy don't know, where is problem. Code is without others errors (only this d.ts files).

Can you help me, what is wrong? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

in your _all.d.ts, you don't need reference to browser.d.ts, as both contain same definitions and hence you are seeing duplicate identifier errors.

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.d.ts" />  
/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Yes, it was mistake with comment. I only have this two line. There isn't any problem.

Comment: I didn't. But references row is not the problem.

Comment: so after removing the reference line also you are getting same error? Have you tried closing your editor and opening again?

Comment: Yes and Yes. But reinstall typings packages helped! So solved! Thanks.